# Darboux integral for non-polynomial ODEs

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, polynomials, differential-equations

Given a polynomial ODE in $n$-dimensions of maximal degree $d$
$$ 
    \dot{x}_j=f_j(x)=\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n=1}^d a_{i_1,\dots,i_n}^j x_1^{i_1}\dots x_n^{i_n} \quad \forall j=1,\ldots,n
  $$
we define an algebraic solution as an any curve $\gamma: [t_0,t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ solving the ODE and fulfilling
$$
G(\gamma(t))=\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n=1}^{d'} b_{i_1,\dots,i_{n}}{\gamma_1(t)}^{i_{1}}\dots {\gamma_n(t)}^{i_n}=0 \quad \forall t \in [t_0,t_1]
$$
for some real coefficients $b_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$.

The Darboux theorem states that if it has $p$ irreducible Darboux polynomials and if
$ p \geq \binom{d+n-1}{n}+1$ then it has a Darboux first integral.

---

Let's assume we are given a linear function space
$$\mathcal{B}=\left\{ F_j(x)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i,j} \psi_i(x) \,\Big\vert\, a \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \right\}$$
by that I mean that we have basis functions $\psi_i$ and coefficients $a_i$. But these basis functions now can be any smooth function. But clearly only finitely many. E.g. in two dimension functions like $\sin(x_1 \cdot x_2), e^{x_1}x_2,cos(x_1+x_2),\ldots$

---

**My question:** Is there still a form of Darboux's theorem but now with the different basis functions? Can we still derive first integral from invariant "algebraic curves". But now algebraic in the basis functions. I.e. in two dimensions if we have $n$ algebraic solutions $\sum_{i=1}^{m'} b_{i,j} \psi_i(x(t))=0 \quad \forall t$ in the basis can we say something about first integrals?